# Fatal error when adding row-actions (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a table by extending the class WP_List_Table. But when i want to add the actions "edit" and "delete" into my rows i do get an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\norskeanalyser\wp-content\plugins\aksjeanalyser\aksjeanalyser.php
>   on line 228

And this is how my function looks:

```
function column_col_name($item){
         $actions = array(
        'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s& hotel=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['id']),
        'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&hotel=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['id']),
    );
    return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['name'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
}
```

Line 228 is this one: `'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s& hotel=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['id']),`

Maybe it has something to do with `$_REQUEST['page']`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some thing like this

`'edit'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s& hotel=%s">Edit</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'edit',$item->id)`

Comment: but when i now click on "Delete", i come to a page which says i haven't capability to access this page. Why this?

Comment: You are logged in from admin account or user account?

Comment: Did you also change 
`'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&hotel=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item->id)`

Comment: Did you add delete 
function `function process_bulk_action() {
global $wpdb;
if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$ids = '';
if(is_array($id)) {
foreach($id as $k=>$v) {
$ids .= $v . ",";
}
$ids = substr($ids, 0, -1);
} else {
$ids = $id;
}
if($ids != '') {
                $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."users` WHERE ID IN ($ids)" );
   }

  }

 }
`

Comment: this function needs to call like `$this->process_bulk_action();` in query function where you set query for fetching records

Comment: I am logged in as admin user and i did also the changes you have mentioned above  but it doesnt help. Im still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you send me file or paste here full code of  file so i can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Can you var_dump($item)?
I believe your $item is not an array.
Try using $item->name, $item->ID instead of $item['name'], $item['id']

If you want to get some property from the object, you need to use the

```
$object->property
```

syntax, not $object['property']